# Проверка почты на существование

Tags: email, валидация

посоветуйте хорошие программы для проверки почты на существование (электронные адреса без пароля), а также чтобы я мог загрузить много мыл (100-150 млн за раз) и программа не зависла :)

Comment: Почтовый сервис проверяет адрес, и если такого нет - возвращает письмо, мол нет такого. Это может сработать несколько раз через определенный промежуток времени без последствий. Но 100-150 млн...вас сразу забанят.

Comment: я имею ввиду, чтобы можно было их вставить за раз, а не делить их по 100-500к

Comment: Даже за 100к адресов вас забанят. Нет таких сервисов в принципе. И хорошо, что нет. Иначе бы брутфорсом перебрали давно все адреса.